# 1 day prepaid subscription Error UNITY Google play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, subscription

Hi i am integrating in app purchase in unity in android. I believe my code is perfect as it is working fine for Consumable, Non Consumable and Subscription products (Auto-renew). But not working for **Prepaid Subscriptions**.

In Google play i have two subscription products, both of them have
Type:prepaid and
Time duration:1Day

When i try to purchase this item i got an error : **No products were found when fetching from the store**
and i have no clue why specifically this is not working while all other products are working fine.

Note: All products are working fine in editor + android device but prepaid sub only works in editor and not on android.

This is my code, and in Google play i have same product "ids" and are active.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;
using System.Collections.Generic;



public class ShopScript : MonoBehaviour, IDetailedStoreListener
{
    IStoreController m_StoreContoller;

    private void Start()
    {
        SetupBuilder();
    }

  
    void SetupBuilder()
    {
        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());

        builder.AddProduct("noads", ProductType.Subscription);
        builder.AddProduct("booster", ProductType.Subscription);

        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }
    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        
        m_StoreContoller = controller;
        CheckSubscription("noads");
        CheckSubscription("booster");
    }
    


    
   

    public void PurchaseNoAds()
    {
        m_StoreContoller.InitiatePurchase("noads");
    }
    public void PurchaseBooster()
    {
        m_StoreContoller.InitiatePurchase("booster");
    }




   
    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs purchaseEvent)
    {
        var product = purchaseEvent.purchasedProduct;

        if (product.definition.id == "noads")//subscribed
        {
            print("no ads purchased");
        }
        if (product.definition.id == "booster")//subscribed
        {
            print("booster purchased");
        }

        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
    }
  





    void CheckSubscription(string id) {

        var subProduct = m_StoreContoller.products.WithID(id);
        if (subProduct != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (subProduct.hasReceipt)
                {
                    var subManager = new SubscriptionManager(subProduct, null);
                    var info = subManager.getSubscriptionInfo();
                   
                    if (info.isSubscribed() == Result.True)
                    {
                        print("We are subscribed");
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        print("Un subscribed");
                        
                    }

                }
                else{
                    print("receipt not found !!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                print("It only work for Google store, app store, amazon store, you are using fake store!!");
            }
        }
        else {
            print("product not found !!");
        }
    }


    #region error handeling
    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
    {
        print("failed" + error);
    }

    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error, string message)
    {
        print("initialize failed" + error + message);
    }



    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product product, PurchaseFailureReason failureReason)
    {
        print("purchase failed" + failureReason);
    }

    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product product, PurchaseFailureDescription failureDescription)
    {
        print(failureDescription.message);
    }
    #endregion



}
```

I tried to purchase "noads" and "booster" which are 1 day sub but got error :"No products were found when fetching from the store"